# Clipping raster in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgis, polygon, clip

I want to clip raster (SRID 32649) with polygon(SRID 4326) into SRID 32648

First I transform raster using query

```
create view ras68 as
select st_transform(rast,32648) as rast
from ras69
```

Then cutting raster 32648 with polygon

```
select st_union(st_clip(rast,1,st_transform(geom,32648),true) )
from ras68, shp
where st_intersects(rast,st_transform(geom,32648))
```

The result has error:

ERROR:  rt_raster_from_two_rasters: The two rasters provided do not have the same alignment
********** Error **********

ERROR: rt_raster_from_two_rasters: The two rasters provided do not have the same alignment
SQL state: XX000

What's my mistake and how to fix that ? (If run st_intersects() only, the result are fine, they overlap)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do your st_transform of raster aligned to a reference raster otherwise each tile gets its own scale etc. so may no longer match up.

Try:

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ras68 as
      WITH ref AS (
       SELECT ST_Transform(rast,32648) As rast_alignto
           FROM ras69 LIMIT 1)
      SELECT st_transform(rast,rast_alignto) as rast
      FROM ras69;
```

and then rerun your union

Comment: Hi, @LR1234567,
Now I have problem about "out of memory" error when I try to clip 70 raster file data. 
what I have to do to get out of this error ?

Comment: Answered in your other question http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/169467/postgresql-out-of-memory